# NLog container name format

Tags: azure, logging, nlog, azure-table-storage, slash

Does NLog not work when container name has '/' without any exception?
I have the following code in one place of my application:

```
    _log.AddLog("TestController", "Just test", LogLevel.INFO);
```

and it works fine (write to my Azure Table Storage). But I have the following code in another place:

```
                _log.AddLog("PricingController/PaymentCreditCard", p_ex.Message, LogService.LogLevel.WARN);
```

and it does not work without any error/exception. Just no write anything. I spent approx 1 hour to search why and found, that without '/' it works. I have read NLog documentation and did not find any word about slash in container name. Or it's a problem of wrapper, which write to Azure Table Storage?

Comment: I haven't used nlog with azure table storage so I don't know how it works but I am assuming that `"PricingController/PaymentCreditCard"` goes in as `PartitionKey` or `RowKey` in the table. If that's the case, the reason for failure could be the presence of `/` character in `PartitionKey` or `RowKey` value. It is not a valid character in `PartitionKey` or `RowKey` value. Please see this link for the list of unallowed characters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx.

Comment: you are right, it's written to partition key. Just problem of wrapper - it does not throw any exception about it, so, I even don't know about lost records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Gaurav Mantri said above, problem is in PartitionKey, where symbol '/' is denied
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx , section **"Characters Disallowed in Key Fields"**

Answer (score 0):

You are writing to Azure Table Storage, Azure Table Storage doesn't have the concept of container, the structure is simple: storage account > Table > Entity, find more information [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/). So you'll need to specify the table name instead of container name and table name of Azure Table Storage doens't allow "/" slash. I suggest you double check the name, I think you might specify a blob container thus it won't work.

Comment: problem was in PartitionKey

Comment: @OlegSh Thanks, I misunderstood the situation here.